# mysql connector in python not working

Tags: python, mysql

i wrote the code as below

```
import mysql.connector
mysql.connector.connect
(host='localhost',database='test2',user='root',password='1234')
```

and saved the file as databas.py.

When i execute the below code from command prompt i am getting error as shown in command_prompt_error.

But when i execute the same  set of commands in python command line link to data base s getting created successfully.(shown in working.png)

[image: command_prompt_error]

[image: working]

please let me know what is the source of the issue

Comment: does python default to python2 or python3?

Comment: You run script on different `Python` version~

Comment: thank u both.@elanor:python defaults to 3.7 version of ptython.          @elanor and Frank:i found the answer.python 3.7 doesnot have my sql connector yet.so when i run in 3.4 only the code is working.thank u both for ur suggestion

Answer (score 1):

python 3.7 does not have my sql connector yet.
so when i run in 3.4 only the commands mentioned above are accepted.